# Hide ribbon for none administrators

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Is it possible to hide the ribbon for none administrators in SharePoint Online and still have the ability to edit forms?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by editing your master page in SharePoint Designer as following:

replace the div `<div id="ms-designer-ribbon">` with this:

```
<div id="ms-designer-ribbon">
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
            <!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly" Permissions="FullMask" EmitDiv="true">-->
                <!--SID:02 {Ribbon Snippet}-->
            <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
        </div>
```

Main thing to note here is the Permission property of the   `SPSecurityTrimmedControl`. Setting this to FullMask will make the ribbon visible only to the users with Full Control permission on the site collection

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can i make it visible if they are editing a form?

Comment: Only update the Site master page with the above HTML. Dont add this HTML to the system master page as there are two paster pages in a SharePoint site.

Comment: But the permissions attribute is "FullMask" ?

Comment: List forms use system master page and we will not add this HTML to that master page to allow ribbon to appear as normal.